# javascript iterate over objects in nested array of objects and filter by ids and return the same original dataset updated

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of nested objects, that i want to keep the objects in `items` that have the `id` equal to one in the filter list that i have as reference.

```js
const data = [{
  "otherStuff": "otherB",
  "items": {
    "item1": [{
        "id": "id1",
        "info": "info1"
      },
      {
        "id": "id2",
        "info": "info22"
      }
    ],
    "item20": [{
      "id": "id3",
      "info": "info5"
    }],
    "item5": [{
        "id": "id4",
        "info": "info6"
      },
      {
        "id": "id5",
        "info": "info7"
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "otherStuff": "otherA",
  "items": {
    "item1": [{
        "id": "id1",
        "info": "info10000"
      },
      {
        "id": "id2",
        "info": "info220000"
      }
    ],
    "item20": [{
      "id": "id3",
      "info": "info5000"
    }],
    "item5": [{
        "id": "id4",
        "info": "info60000"
      },
      {
        "id": "id5",
        "info": "info7000"
      }
    ]
  }
}];

const keep = ['id4', 'id2'];
keep.forEach(function(val) {
  data.forEach(function(entry, index){
      const entrySelected = [];
      Object.keys(entry.items).forEach(item => {
        var match = entry.items[item].find(obj => obj.id === val);
        if (match) {
          entrySelected.push(match)
        }
      });
      data[index].items = entrySelected;
  });
})
console.log(data)
```

I am getting an error right now, 
but the idea is to get the following output:

```
 [
        {
            "otherStuff": "otherB",
            "items": [
                    {
                          "id": "id2",
                          "info": "info22"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "id4",
                        "info": "info6"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "otherStuff": "otherA",
            "items": [
                    {
                          "id": "id2",
                          "info": "info220000"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "id4",
                        "info": "info60000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the values of the objects and then reduce the wanted items for a new array. Later assing this to `items`.

```js
var data = [{ otherStuff: "otherB", items: { item1: [{ id: "id1", info: "info1" }, { id: "id2", info: "info22" }], item20: [{ id: "id3", info: "info5" }], item5: [{ id: "id4", info: "info6" }, { id: "id5", info: "info7" }] } }, { otherStuff: "otherA", items: { item1: [{ id: "id1", info: "info10000" }, { id: "id2", info: "info220000" }], item20: [{ id: "id3", info: "info5000" }], item5: [{ id: "id4", info: "info60000" }, { id: "id5", info: "info7000" }] } }],
    keep = ['id4', 'id2'];

data.forEach(o =>
    o.items = Object
        .keys(o.items)
        .reduce((r, k) => o
            .items[k]
            .reduce((s, p) => s.concat(keep.includes(p.id) ? p : []), r), []));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With a filter for arrays.

```js
var data = [{ otherStuff: "otherB", items: { item1: [{ id: "id1", info: "info1" }, { id: "id2", info: "info22" }], item20: [{ id: "id3", info: "info5" }], item5: [{ id: "id4", info: "info6" }, { id: "id5", info: "info7" }] } }, { otherStuff: "otherA", items: { item1: [{ id: "id1", info: "info10000" }, { id: "id2", info: "info220000" }], item20: [{ id: "id3", info: "info5000" }], item5: [{ id: "id4", info: "info60000" }, { id: "id5", info: "info7000" }] } }],
    keep = ['id4', 'id2'];

data.forEach(o =>
    o.items = Object
        .keys(o.items)
        .filter(k => Array.isArray(o.items[k]))
        .reduce((r, k) => o
            .items[k]
            .reduce((s, p) => s.concat(keep.includes(p.id) ? p : []), r), []));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: could you suggest a solution without using Object.values ?

Comment: `TypeError: o.items[k].reduce is not a function` i am getting this error when running inside my app. but when i run it as a separate script, it works. any ideas?

Comment: maybe you have in your data not an array for `o.items[k]`

Comment: i am using the same data in the script as hardcoded, it works, but when it is coming from DB, it is not. they are the same data, just copy pasted .

Comment: maybe you have an additional property, which is not in the hard coded object. please try the second one with a filter for items who are not arrays.

Comment: Given that this is done via a function `function filterData(keep, data) {
return data.forEach(o =>
    o.items = Object
        .keys(o.items)
        .filter(k => Array.isArray(o.items[k]))
        .reduce((r, k) => o
            .items[k]
            .reduce((s, p) => s.concat(keep.includes(p.id) ? p : []), r), []));

}`

it returns empty.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: how can i return the filtered results in this case?

Comment: your function returns `undefined`, because `forEach` returns by design `undefined`. for returning the mutated `data`, you need to return it at the end of the function.

Comment: OMG, right now it works. so why the first solution is not working?